# How to SVG transition programmatically

Tags: javascript, svg

I'd like to fade this (browser rendered) SVG element in and out (change the opacity over 1 second). I'm looking for an example of javaScript to fade it in and fade it out (start an animation) *programmatically*. I see examples of transitions using the `<animate>` element, but all the examples focus on controlling the animation with either a button click, a mouseevent, or simply when the page loads.

```
<svg  x="100" y="100px" opacity="1">
  <rect x="0px" height="60px" width="60px" fill="blue" />
</svg>
```

Comment: perhaps an odd question, but: "why?". And if you really have to, why not just use CSS with an `svg { opacity; 1; transition: opacity 1s; } svg.fadeout { opacity: 0}` and then setting the fadeout class, with a transition end JS handler to add or remove that class?

Comment: My criteria for fading in and out is not user input, but client window size. My trials with css were not successful, perhaps I had some syntax issue. I will revisit.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. Constantly fading in and out is not contingent on anything, so I believe your post is missing the part that explains what's supposed to trigger the fade in/out and whether you want it to happen once, or continuously.

Comment: Something has to trigger the event, if not by a click, mouse event or page load, how were you thinking it would be triggered?

Comment: The client browser window has a field of various svg shapes drawn. If the user resizes the browser window so that an svg shape is partially clipped by the right or bottom edge of the window, that shape will gracefully fade out. If a user expands the size of the window, any shapes now wholly included will gracefully fade back in. A window-resize event handler checks window.innerHeight and window.innerWidth to ascertain the current size of the window. So it's driven by that and not by clicks or mouseovers.

Answer (score 0):

To alter an attribute in Javascript, adding an 'id' to the element:

```
<svg id="mysvg" x="100" y="100px" opacity="1">
    <rect x="0px" height="60px" width="60px" fill="blue" />
</svg>
```

you can set the 'opacity' attribute like:

```
var elem= document.getElementById("mysvg");
elem.setAttribute( 'opacity', 0.5 );
```

or, if you are using jQuery:

```
$('#mysvg').attr('opacity',0.8);
```

to change this over time you need a timer e.g.

```
var fadeOut= function(){ 
    var elem=document.getElementById("mysvg"); 
    var opacity= elem.getAttribute('opacity')-0.05;
    if( opacity < 0.05 ){
        opacity=0; 
    }
    elem.setAttribute('opacity',opacity); 
    if( opacity > 0 ) 
        setTimeout( fadeOut, 50 );
};

fadeOut();
```